# Идентификатор не найдён / Идентификатор не определён

Tags: c++

Есть код на вижле (не мой, какая именно вижла использовалась - неизвестно). Я же использую 19-го. Компилятор ругается на gets:

```
идентификатор "gets" не определён
gets: идентификатор не найден
```

Код:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    char in_string [500]; // строковый массив для ввода 
    cout << "Vvod stroki" << endl;
    gets (in_string); //
    char symbol = '!';

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(in_string); i++) {
        if (i == 1)  in_string[i] = symbol;
        if (in_string[i] == ' ' and in_string[i + 2] != ' ') { //если i-тый символ не является пробелом, а предыдущий - пробелом, то это первый символ в слове
            in_string[i + 2] = symbol;
        }
    }
    cout << in_string << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Вы забыли задать вопрос.

Comment: Вообще, конечно, странно, ведь cstdio подключен. Замени на fgets, тем более, что он надёжнее.

Comment: Вот, что нашел: "The most recent revision of the C standard (2011) has definitively removed this function from its specification. The function is deprecated in C++ (as of 2011 standard, which follows C99+TC3).".

Answer (score 2):

В стандартных библиотеках языков С и С++ уже давно нет никакого `gets`. Потому компилятор и ругается.

Comment: как тогда исправить?

Comment: @Wilomen `cin`'ом считать, что же еще.